# How can I visualize a nearest neighbor algorithm coming from scikitlearn

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, knn

I've obtained a KNeighborsRegressor from an automated Machine Learning process (using TPOT). Now I'd like to visualize when data goes through the algorithm:

```
exported_pipeline = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=6, p=1, weights="distance")
exported_pipeline.fit(training_features, training_target)
results = exported_pipeline.predict(testing_features)

max_error = (results-testing_target).argmax()
idx = (results-testing_target).argmax()   # maximum prediction error occurs here
print(f'MAX_ERROR={max_error} at index={idx}')
```

Comment: What is it you want to visualize?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't superclear. I would like to *explain* the regression. As in viewing how the 6 nearest neighbors contribute to the predicted value.

Comment: You can get the 6 nearest neighbors with the kneighbors method.